# Active Directory VBScript Issue

Tags: windows, vbscript, active-directory

I'm creating a script to assign a Active Directory user to a group but I want to use a text box input instead of predefining the username. I know I'm doing something stupid here but `strUserName` is a predefined `dim` value at the top of the code.

```
userPath = "LDAP://cn=users" & "cn=" & strUserName) & "cn=users,dc=domain......."
```

Comment: Remove the `)` its just floating there outside of a string and you need a `,` delimiter between each key/value

Comment: "cn=" & strUserName, &

Comment: like that then yeah?

Comment: `userPath = "LDAP://cn=users," & "cn=" & strUserName & ",cn=users,dc=domain......."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spurious `cn=users` before the username, a spurious parenthesis after the username, and you must have commas between all path segments.

```
userPath = "LDAP://cn=" & strUserName & ",cn=users,dc=example,dc=org"
```